# C array error: expression must have a constant value

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass values of two variables to be the dimension of the **students_grades_db** array, but it doesn't work and I don't know why, as both are **constant variables**.

`const int number_students = 4;`

`const int number_of_notes = 4;`

`float students_grades_db[number_students][number_of_notes] = {0};`

It doesn't work :(

Comment: they are `const` variables not constant variables.  C does not not have constant variables (C++ has constexpr which can give named constant expressions).

Answer (score 2):

A global array declaration must have constant expressions for index sizes.  References to variables (even `const` variables) are not constant expressions, so can't be used.

You can instead use preprocessor macros that expand to constant literals:

```
#define number_of_students  4
#define number_of_notes     4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare an array outside a function at *file scope*, it will then get *static storage duration*. All variables with static storage duration must have compile-time constants as initializers and if they are arrays, the array sizes must also be compile-time constants.

This means that the size has to be something like an integer constant `123` or an expression containing only integer constants.

The `const` keyword, non-intuitively, does not make something a compile-time constant, it only makes something read-only. C and C++ are different here, you code would work in C++.

Possible solutions:

- Move `students_grades_db` inside a function. Then you can declare array sizes using any kind of expression, including common `int` variables. You probably shouldn't declare that array as "global" anyhow.
- Or swap out your constants for `#define number_students 4`.